# Passing in a type as an argument in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm making a method that animates a transition from one view controller to another in Swift.

The only thing that varies from method call to method call is the particular subclass of `UIViewController`.

Therefore, I'm assuming the only things I need to pass in for the method to work the way I want it to is not the instance of a subclass of `UIViewController` but simply the subclass type itself. How would I write this in Swift?

```
 func doAnimation(fromType, toType) { //don't pass in instances, but types to be instantiated (this is the part that I need help with)
      ... //declare fromVC and toVC 
        let topVC = !self.isPresenting ? fromVC as fromType : toVC as toType //assert what type top view controller will be be
        let bottomVC = !self.isPresenting ? fromVC as! fromType : toVC as toType //assert what type bottom view controller will be
      ...

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your animation need to instantiate the view controllers or do they already exist?  If they already exist then you don't even need to know the types; they are just `UIViewControllers`.

Comment: I'm instantiating `topVC` and `bottomVC` with `fromVC` and `toVC` cast as `fromType` and `toType`

Comment: So  `doAnimation` is responsible for creating the VCs?   I presume these ViewControllers define their contents programatically rather than using storyboard/nib files

Comment: The confusion here is in `// declare fromVC and toVC`. Do you believe you already know how to create these, or is that the question? (It's solvable, but you need to give some more information about how you expect these to be instantiated. NIB, StoryBoard, `init`, etc.) You don't need to assert types with `as`; you need to use the types to create the objects.

Answer (score -1):

```
import Foundation

class C {}

func f<T>(type: T) {
    switch type {
    case is Int.Type:
        print("Integer type")
    case is String.Type:
        print("String type")
    case is C.Type:
        print("C type")
    default:
        print("something else ... :-)")
    }
}

f(Int.self)     // Integer type
f(C.self)       // C type
f(String.self)  // String type
f(Any.self)     // something else ... :-)
```

Comment: Request:  func doAnimation(fromType, toType) { //don't pass in instances, but types to be instantiated (this is the part that I need help with) Answer: i show how to check what type was pass to function. or is the question how to make the  instance ???

Comment: The question isn't clear and I suspect that the OP doesn't actually know what they want to do or has the wrong idea, but a series of case statements is unlikely to lead to flexible and maintainable code.